# Environment variables not working in Phalcon Config

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a Phalcon project with this library added: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv. This library is meant to load some environment variables from a .env file. I created such a file and put it in my project.

```
VERSION_NUMBER=3.14 

DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_NAME=test
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PASS=root
```

I rewrote my `loader.php` file to the code below:

```
<?php
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Test\Models' => $config->application->modelsDir,
    'Test\Controllers' => $config->application->controllersDir,
    'Test\Forms' => $config->application->formsDir,
    'Test\Classes' => $config->application->classesDir,
    'Test\Classes\Excel' => $config->application->excelDir,
    'Test' => $config->application->libraryDir
));

$loader->register();

// Use composer autoloader to load vendor classes
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->required(['DATABASE_HOST', 'DATABASE_NAME', 'DATABASE_USER', 'DATABASE_PASS']);
$dotenv->overload();
```

And in my config file I replaced the keys with the environment variables:

```
'database' => array(
    'adapter'  => 'Mysql',
    'host'     => getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
    'username' => getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DATABASE_PASS'),
    'dbname'   => getenv('DATABASE_NAME')
),
```

I can echo `getenv('VERSION_NUMBER')` where I want and it works every time, but when I try to use this config file the variables are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not detect the current url in config.php and define rules there? I`m a bit skeptical (if someone had access to scripts he would have to .env files as well), my opinion

Comment: Because I like the idea of being able to set global variables and because we have lots of different clients and thus urls, so I think this is the cleaner solution. I'm not doing this because of the so-called "added security".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the source code excerpts you've provided, there is no reason why it shouldn't work. I can only make assumptions, but since I'm currently developing a project which uses Dotenv as well, I'd like to point out two possibilities.

Firstly, I'm not sure why you're using the `overload()` Method. It's completely sufficient to load Dotenv like this in your `public/index.php`:

```
define('APP_PATH', realpath('..'));
include APP_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APP_PATH);
$dotenv->load();
```

This brings me to the second and most likely source of your problem:

You're loading Dotenv in the `loader.php` file. In most Phalcon example projects, that one is loaded after the config, therefore your Env variables aren't set at that point yet. Include the code I mentioned in your `index.php` and you should be good.